# Vertx Sessionhandler Creating new Session for EVERY Request

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle, java-vertx-web

I have a login page in a nextjs app running on port 3000. The login page calls /sign-in api on vertx server on port 8082. After successful login, the user is redirect from login page to dashboard page which on same nexjs app. From dashboard, I call other secure apis on the vertx server. However, vertx is creating new session for every request -- meaning after user is redirected to dashboard page, the session data created in the login page is not available, so repeating the login cycle. Complete code:

```
public class HttpServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(HttpServerVerticle.class);

    public static final String CONFIG_HTTP_SERVER_PORT = "http.server.port";

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> promise) throws Exception {

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        LocalSessionStore sessionStore = LocalSessionStore.create(vertx);

        SessionHandler sessionHandler = SessionHandler.create(sessionStore)
                                        .setCookieSecureFlag(true)
                                        .setCookieHttpOnlyFlag(true)
                                        .setCookieSameSite(CookieSameSite.NONE)
                                        .setSessionCookiePath("/");//setSessionCookieName("vid");

        router.route().handler(sessionHandler);

        Handler<RoutingContext> loginHandler = ctx -> {
            Session session = ctx.session();
            System.out.println("Session at login handler for " + ctx.request().absoluteURI());
            System.out.println(session.id());
            System.out.println(session.value());
            if(session != null && session.get("my-session") != null){
                ctx.next();
            }
            else {
                ctx.response()
                .setStatusCode(302)
                .putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
                .putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
                .putHeader("Location", "http://localhost:3000/login")
                .end();
            }
        };
        router.route("/api/*").handler(loginHandler);

        CorsHandler corsHandler = CorsHandler.create()
            .addOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
            .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
            .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
            .allowedHeader("Content-Type")
            .allowCredentials(true);

        router.route().handler(corsHandler);


        router.post().handler(BodyHandler.create());
   

        router.post("/v/sign-in").handler(this::logIn);


        router.post("/api/do-protected-work").handler(this::createLinkToken);

       
        int portNumber = System.getenv("HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT") != null ?
                Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT")) : config().getInteger(CONFIG_HTTP_SERVER_PORT, 8082);

        System.out.println("Connecting to por number: " + portNumber);

        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
        server
                .requestHandler(router)
                .listen(portNumber, ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                        LOGGER.info("HTTP server running on port " + portNumber);
                        promise.complete();
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.error("Could not start a HTTP server", ar.cause());
                        promise.fail(ar.cause());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void createLinkToken(RoutingContext context) {
        System.out.println("Session=====================================================================");
        System.out.println(context.session().id());
        System.out.println(context.session().value());
        System.out.println((String)context.session().get("my-session"));
        JsonObject request = context.body().asJsonObject();
        LOGGER.info("Create link token request received -- {}.", request);
        vertx.eventBus().request("_set_plaid_link_token_", request, new DeliveryOptions(), reply -> {
            if(reply.succeeded()){
                context.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                context.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                context.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
                context.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                context.response().setStatusCode(200).end(Json.encodePrettily(reply.result().body()));
            } else {
                LOGGER.info(reply.cause().getMessage());
                context.response().setStatusCode(400).end(Json.encodePrettily(reply.cause().getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }

    private void logIn(RoutingContext context) {
        Session session = context.session();
        System.out.println("Session at login");
        System.out.println(session.id());
        System.out.println(session.value());
        JsonObject request = context.body().asJsonObject();
        LOGGER.info("Send verification text request received -- {}.", request);
        String textCode = request.getString("textCode");
        LOGGER.info("Text code is {}", textCode);
        request.put("textCode", textCode);
        vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject>request("__address___", request, new DeliveryOptions(), sendReply -> {
            if(sendReply.succeeded()){
                context.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
                String id = sendReply.result().body().getString("result");
                if(null != id) {
                    System.out.println("putting the id in the session");
                    response.put("Result", "Succeeded");
                    context.session().put("my-session", id);
                }
                else {
                    response.put("Result", "Failed");
                }
                context.response().setStatusCode(200).end(Json.encodePrettily(response));
            }
            else {
                LOGGER.info(sendReply.cause().getMessage());
                context.response().setStatusCode(400).end(Json.encodePrettily(sendReply.cause().getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Session handler depends on cookie store, which is missing

Add `router.route().handler(CookieHandler.create())` before the session handler

Comment: CookieHandler is not available in vertx 4 and later versions.